# Developing Concave Mirror Image Formation Simulation Using three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

How to draw concave mirror and incident ray and reflected ray.
I did following but leads to very annoying result.
I used ellipseCurve to draw mirror.

```
var curve = new THREE.EllipseCurve(
0,  0,            // ax, aY
10, 10,           // xRadius, yRadius
0,  2 * Math.PI,  // aStartAngle, aEndAngle
false,            // aClockwise
0                 // aRotation
);
var path = new THREE.Path( curve.getPoints( 50 ) ); 
var geometry = path.createPointsGeometry( 50 );
var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color : 0xff0000 } );
// Create the final object to add to the scene
var ellipse = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );
scene.add(ellipse);
```

Used Following to draw object and incident ray and reflected ray by changing source point and destination point

```
var sourcePos= new THREE.Vector3(ObjectPositionX,ObjectPositionY,0);
var targetPos = new THREE.Vector3(FocusPointX,FocusPointY,0);
var direction = new THREE.Vector3().sub(targetPos, sourcePos);
var rayParallel = new THREE.ArrowHelper(direction.clone().normalize(), sourcePos, direction.length(), 0x00ff00);
scene.add(rayParallel);
```

Screen shot of my Result is
[Image Formed by concave mirror](http://prnt.sc/elps2c)

Suggesting any other method to solve this is also appreciated.

Comment: (Just to say: in your code, `targetPos` is defined twice and `sourcePos` is not defined.) What do you call `ObjectPosition`?

Comment: That was my mistake.ObjectPosition means x,y cordinate where object is located.

Comment: Do you mean the position in the world or the position on the surface of the mirror?

Comment: Position of Object on Principle Axis

Comment: OK, so you compute the coordinates of the contact point with the equation of the curve, right?